# customizing preg_match

Tags: php, string, preg-match

How do i preg_match an string to match the following format in php:

```
 $m="123/456789/01";

if(pregmatch(????, $m){
   // match
}else{
   // doesn't match
}
```

i.e. 3 digits + "/" + 6 digits + "/" + 2 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my try :)

```
if(preg_match('/[0-9]{3}\/[0-9]{6}\/[0-9]{2}/', $m)
{
    // match
}
else
{
    // Doesn't match
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (preg_match("#\d{3}/\d{6}/\d{2}#", $string)) {
  // yeah
} else {
  // nope
}
```

have a look at [Pattern Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) specifically [Escape sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you would like to parse, regular expressions are not always needed:

```
$m="123/456789/01";

if(3 == count(sscanf($m, '%d/%d/%d'))) {
   // match
}else{
   // doesn't match
}
```